# Get permissions with @client.event on_message (Discord.py)

Tags: python, permissions, discord, discord.py

I want to see if `message.author` has the `Manage Server` permission to change the prefix. I want to use `@client.event` instead of `@bot.command` or others. Please tell me how to do it, thank you!

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(f'{prefix}prefix'):
    message.channel.guild.author.guild_permissions
    requestList = message.content.split()
    if len(requestList) == 2:
      prefixData[guildID] = requestList[1] #'str' object does not support item assignment
      await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + "\n" + f"The new prefix is {requestList[1]}")
    else:
      await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + "\n" + "ERROR")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guild_permissions` is an attribute of `Member` also it seems prefixData is a string instead of a dict

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(m):
    if not m.guild: return # DM Message
    if m.author.guild_permissions.manage_guild and m.content.startswith(f'{prefix}prefix'):
        # change prefix code
```